# LDAP Integration with Trusted Active Directory Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query, trust

**Overview**

There are two domains: domainA and domainB. I am seeking to make the configuration, so that a web server from domainB can leverage an AD service account in another domainA.

[image: Ad Diagram]

In the environment where domainB is located, I have a web server that needs to reach back to domainA to be able to query all of the users. The owners of the domainA account created a service account user that allows domainB to query the user base. We have established that the account works when testing directly from the domainB controller to the domainA controller. When we try to run a ldapsearch from the web server using the service account user, we run into some issues:

```
[ec2-user@hostname ~]$ ldapsearch -x -LLL -h $domainB_ipAddress -D $service_account_username -w $ad_pwd -b "OU=xxxxx,DC=xxxxx,DC=xxxxx,DC=xxxxx" 

ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
        additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042A, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839
```

Note: This user is successfully authenticated from the domainB AD controller to the domainA AD controller using ldp.exe bind, so I believe the credentials are ok.

**Our Current Approach**

Based on the feedback I have received from my team, we should be making the request of the service account from domainB web server to the domainB controller, which will then forward this information on to the trusted domainA controller and return back the desired information back to the domainB web server.

I'm a little confused about how this forwarding is supposed to occur, but we have a requirement that we cannot reach directly into the domainA controller from any non-AD server from domainB.

**Requested Feedback**

1. Is it correct to assume that any request should be forwarded from the domainB controller to the domainA controller? If so, what needs to be in place for that to happen?
2. If requests cannot be forwarded, what would we need to do to get users from the trusted domainA into the domainB controller, so that the service account could reference them there?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
data 52e
```

[Means](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1300-1699-):

> **ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE**
>
> 1326 (0x52E)
>
> The user name or password is incorrect.

You said the service account is from domainA, but you're connecting to domainB. That would only work if there is at least a one-way trust between the two domains: if domainB trusts domainA. From your description, I don't think that is the case. If you connect to domainB, you need to authenticate with a domainB account.

And the only way there would be any forwarding is if there was a trust. The term for this is a "referral". That would happen if there is a trust between the domains and you, for example, try to bind to a user in one domain while connected to the other. The server would return a "referral" telling you to go connect to the other domain.